# Appending a set with a text file

Tags: java

If I have a result stored in the following set:

```
Set<Integer> dataset = new HashSet<>();
```

Also, I have this text file:

```
File file = new File("\Users\Test.txt");
```

**My goal is to append the set `dataset` with the `Test.txt` (Write it at the end of Test.txt or possibly append both to a new text file).** I tried first to wrap my `dataset` using `BufferedReader` so I can prepare it for appending but I got stuck because the `InputStreamReader` does not accept Sets. I don't know how to fix it to proceed:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataset)); // Error Here
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should proceed like this:

```
    Set<Integer> dataset = new HashSet<>();
    dataset.add(8);
    dataset.add(3);
    dataset.add(7);
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("\\Users\\Test.txt", true); // true -> append
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
        out.println(dataset);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("An exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Note that we used a try with resources to automatically close the closable that were open in the `try` part.

Comment: Thank you very much... Appreciate your response

Comment: If you don't mind, Is there another wrapper than `PrintWriter` because the set is printed as a list of decimal digits.

Comment: You're welcome! Can you show me the expected output: how do you wish the set to be printed?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in the path, you have to escape the '\':

```
File file = new File("\\Users\\Test.txt");
```